# How to use Powershell to download and pipe to execution with arguments

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to use powershell to download and execute a file with arguments:

```
. { iwr -useb https://github.com/int0x33/nc.exe/blob/master/nc64.exe?raw=true } | iex; <IP> 9001
```

I get this error:

```
Unexpected token '9001' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you want to download you should be using `-OutFile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) (`ie`) is for interpreting and executing *text* as *PowerShell code*<sup>[1]</sup> - you can't use it to execute a *binary* download directly (which PowerShell fundamentally doesn't support).

Instead, use [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)'s (`iwr`'s) `-OutFile` parameter to download the binary content *to a local file* and execute the latter:

```sh
iwr -useb https://github.com/int0x33/nc.exe/blob/master/nc64.exe?raw=true -OutFile ./nc64.exe

./nc64.exe $someIp 9001
```

---

<sup>[1] The obligatory warning: `Invoke-Expression`  (`iex`) should generally be *avoided* and used only as a *last resort*, due to its inherent security risks. Superior alternatives are usually available. If there truly is no alternative, only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).</sup>